# ADTK Outlier detection/filtering in Python

Tags: python, detection, outliers

I am trying to fine anomalies in the data set I have. This is CPU usage data for a process.

My data looks something like below
[image]

My code to find anomalies looks like something below

```
outlier_detector = OutlierDetector(LocalOutlierFactor(contamination=0.05))
anomalies = outlier_detector.fit_detect(df_anomaly)
print(anomalies)
```

The anomalies output shows me something like below

[image]

How can I filter the anomalies output for all values which have ***True*** in the set? Is anomalies output a dataframe or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was answered by Contributors on GitHub.

The anomalies object is a `pandas.core.series.Series`
You can convert it to a list and use the data in your own plot.

```
# With datetime and boolean
anomailes_list = anomalies.reset_index().values.tolist()
anomailes_list
```

```
# Just boolean results
anomailes_list = anomalies.to_list()
anomailes_list

# List of values that are True
anomalies_true = [value for value in anomalies.to_list() if value]
```